# Given a phone number in words, convert the number to digits

Tags: python, list, digits

The below code work's fine for

```
Input: "two one nine six eight one six four six zero"

Output: "2196816460"
```

```
n=s.split()
    l=[]
    for val in n:
        if(val=='zero'):
            l.append('0')
        elif(val=='one'):
            l.append("1")
        elif(val=='two'):
            l.append("2")
        elif(val=='three'):
            l.append("3")
        elif(val=='four'):
            l.append("4")
        elif(val=="five"):
            l.append("5")
        elif(val=="six"):
            l.append("6")
        elif(val=="seven"):
            l.append("7")
        elif(val=="eight"):
            l.append("8")
        elif(val=="nine"):
            l.append("9")
    new = ''.join(l)
    return new
```

But what if,

Input: "five eight double two double two four eight five six"
Required Output should be : 5822224856
or,
Input: "five one zero six triple eight nine six four"
Required Output should be : 5106888964
How can the above code be modified?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "But what if?" Okay, what should the output be in those cases? According to what logic? What do you want the code to do differently from what it does now? Try to write that out for yourself, in plain English words, and then try to write new code to solve the problem by thinking about the logical steps that need to be taken. (Hint: when the word `double` appears in the input, does that immediately tell you to output something? Or should you instead *remember* that you saw the word `double`, in order to *change* what happens *next time* through the loop?)

Comment: I modified the question. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you want the code to do. You [should](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) still try to think about how to solve the problem before posting on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create another mapping for the quantity modifiers, and multiply the digit string by the preceding modifier.

```
digits = {
    "zero": "0",
    "one": "1",
    "two": "2",
    "three": "3",
    "four": "4",
    "five": "5",
    "six": "6",
    "seven": "7",
    "eight": "8",
    "nine": "9",
}

modifiers = {
    "double": 2,
    "triple": 3,
}

number = ""
n = 1
for word in input("? ").split():
    if word in modifiers:
        n *= modifiers[word]
    else:
        number += n * digits[word]
        n = 1
print(number)
```

```
? five eight double two double two four eight five six
5822224856
```

Comment: OP: Take note of how `n` is used in this code - this is what I described in the original comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable to hold the repetitions of the next number.

The variable starts with value `1`.

When get a repetition word (`'triple'`) , then update the variable correspondingly.

When get a number (`'three'`), add to the list and update the variable back to `1`

Also instead of using `else..if` you can use a dictionary:

```
repeat = 1
repeat_dict = {'double':2, 'triple':3}:

n=s.split()
l=[]
for val in n:
    if val in repeat_dict:   # got a repeat word
        repeat = repeat_dict[val]
    else:
          
        if(val=='zero'):
            l.append('0' * repeat) 
        elif(val=='one'):
            l.append("1" * repeat)
        elif(val=='two'):
            l.append("2" * repeat)
        elif(val=='three'):
            l.append("3" * repeat)
        elif(val=='four'):
            l.append("4" * repeat)
        elif(val=="five"):
            l.append("5" * repeat)
        elif(val=="six"):
            l.append("6" * repeat)
        elif(val=="seven"):
            l.append("7" * repeat)
        elif(val=="eight"):
            l.append("8" * repeat)
        elif(val=="nine"):
            l.append("9" * repeat)
        repeat = 1
new = ''.join(l)
return new
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

unordered_map<string, string> wordToDigit = {
    {"zero", "0"}, {"one", "1"}, {"two", "2"}, {"three", "3"}, {"four", "4"},
    {"five", "5"}, {"six", "6"}, {"seven", "7"}, {"eight", "8"}, {"nine", "9"}
};

string convertPhoneNumberToDigits(const string& phoneNumberInWords) {
    istringstream iss(phoneNumberInWords);
    string word, previousWord;
    string result = "";

    while (iss >> word) {
        if (word == "double" || word == "triple") {
            previousWord = word;
        } else {
            if (previousWord == "double") {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    result += wordToDigit[word];
                }
                previousWord = "";
            } else if (previousWord == "triple") {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    result += wordToDigit[word];
                }
                previousWord = "";
            } else {
                result += wordToDigit[word];
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    string input= "five one zero two four eight zero double three two";
    // cout << "Enter the phone number in words: ";
    // getline(cin, input);

    string result = convertPhoneNumberToDigits(input);
    cout << "Phone number in digits: " << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it works for all test cases including double and triple

Answer (score 0):

package org.pavan;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneNumber {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine(); 
        convertToNumber(input);
   
}

public static String convertwordtonumber(String number)
{
    
    switch(number)
    {
    case "one":
        return "1";
    
        
    case "two":
        return "2";
    
        
    case "three":
        return "3";
    
        
    case "four":
        return "4";
    
        
    case "five":
        return "5";
    
        
    case "six":
        return "6";
    
        
    case "seven":
        return "7";
    
        
    case "eight":
        return "8";
    
        
    case "nine":
        return "9";
    
        
    case "zero":
        return "0";
            
    default:
        return "Invalid String";
    }
    
}
  
public static void convertToNumber(String input) {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String[] words = input.split(" ");
    
    
    for(int i=0;i<=words.length-1;i++)
    {
        
        if(words[i].equals("double"))
        {
            String num = convertwordtonumber(words[i+1]);
            result.append(num);
            result.append(num);
            i++;
            
        }
        
        else if(words[i].equals("triple")) {
            
            String num1 = convertwordtonumber(words[i+1]);
            result.append(num1);
            result.append(num1);
            result.append(num1);
            i++;
        }
        else if(words[i]!="triple" && words[i]!="double"){
            
            String num2 = convertwordtonumber(words[i]);
            result.append(num2);
            
        }
        
        
    }
    System.out.println(result);
 
         }
  
}
```